# Changing name of main actvity, hard-coding text

Tags: android, android-studio, resources

I'm a noob who has a book on Android programming that is using an  older version of Android Studio. I have Android Studio 3.3. I want to learn on the latest Android Studio, but the steps to naming an activity are completely bypassed in AS v3.3. The book names the activity beer activity, so I thought I would just rename `main activity` to `beer activity`. Error things going red, arghh...

I think I figured out how to rename things in the coding and I got rid of a lot of red, but it crashed when compiling. Then I renamed the main activity in my manifest. Now it runs with title, but won't display text says hard-coding no good. I still get a little lightbulb that complains about resources, and I think I still need to change something somewhere.

Here is the XML code that was named main something, I think. I forgot. Is this code not usable anymore in 3.3? I ran into deprecated things several times. I thought I was buying an up-to-date book copyright November 2018, but Android Studio 3.3 just came out recently, the stable version I think.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.hfad.beeradvisor.FindBeerActivity"> (changed name here)

   <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is text view" (wont display)
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The **Activity name** is referenced in the **manifest** (or maybe a */res/values/string.xml* to save from hard-coding repetition), that name and path must exist as a **real file** (with name also correct *inside* the file) and layouts that reference *tools:context* **should** (but don't always have to be) be correct. Basically change ever occurrence of the name you want to change in your project [via search or otherwise] (It's called refactoring). Please show the relevant code so we can help you, logcat, manifest etc...

Comment: jon Goodwin I finally got it, and now thanks to you for mentioning the string thing my title is correct. I did have the names changed correctly but somehow type textureview instead of textview and never caught it unitl I walked away and came back. now text displays